# A clock cycle unwanted delay in incrementing counter withouth state machine

Tags: vhdl

[image: screenshot for the simulation]

I am trying to run a simple counter(`v_bincount`) starting from 0 to the time when the `s_saxis_tlast` goes high. It starts counting when `s_saxis_tuser_in` is high. It starts from 0 however the value of the counter remains 0 for one more clock cycle even though `v_bincount` is a shared variable and not a signal.

```
p_count: process(clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge (clk)) then
     if (s_saxis_tvalid_in = '1')and (s_saxis_tready_out = '1') then
        if(s_saxis_tuser_in ='1') then
           v_bincount1 := 0;
           v_idcount1  := 0;
        else
           if (s_saxis_tlast_in = '0') then
              v_bincount1 := v_bincount1 + 1;

           else
              v_bincount1 := 0;
              v_idcount1 := v_idcount1 + 1;
           end if;
        end if;
     else 
        v_bincount1 := 0;
        v_idcount1  := 0;
     end if;

  end if; 
end process p_count;
```

Comment: You might try saving that type of image as .png or .gif to improve the quality.

Comment: Please provide a complete set of code.

Answer (score 1):

The simulation is what you would assume. On the lowering edge of the tuser_in, it is still '1' at the clock edge.

I would suggest *not* to use shared variable here. Instead, have a combinatorial counter with signals which increment the value according to your wishes and then clocked process to assign the value to a register e.g.:

```
p_count_r : process(clk)
begin                  
  if (rising_edge (clk)) then
    s_bin_count_r <= s_bin_count;
    s_id_count_r <= s_id_count;
  end if; 
end process p_count_r;
```

and in the combinatorial process use the s_bin_count_r on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I will try the solution provided.